# $n\times n$ matrix determinant of rook configuration

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

We place $n$ rooks on an $n\times n$ chessboard in such a way that they don't threaten each other. To each such placement corresponds an $n\times n$ matrix in which there is a $1$ at the position of the rooks and $0$ at the other places. What is the determinant of the matrices obtained this way? Thanks!

Comment: The identity matrix is an example of a configuration that fits the requirements. And clearly, it has determinant 1.

Comment: @Raskolnikov but there isn't only 1 rook configuration. isn't determinant supposed to be the sum of all these different configurations using the original formula?

Comment: Are you asking what possible values the determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix can have, or the sum of all the determinants over all rook configurations?

Comment: @Arthur Is the possible values of such matrix only 1? or 1 and -1?

Comment: These are known as _Permutation Matrices_ and you can find a lot more information about them under that name.

Comment: @Nima Try to find such a matrix with determinant -1. It shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: @Arthur Yeah I found a few :D anyway thanks everyone

Comment: I guess the $n$ rooks are all of different colors? Because rooks of the same color don't threaten each other, so any placement is possible, and $0$ is a possible value for the determinant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be $(-1)^k$ where $k$ is the number of row and column swaps you need to make from the identity matrix to obtain the matrix that you get from the rook configuration.